# Error in If Condition in Trigger

Tags: trigger

This is part of my Trigger where I am checking the Picklist field Value, Here Unit_type__c is a Picklist and "Studio" is a Value but when I am Checking this value it Shows this Error.

Here it is in 3rd Line  **if(opp.Unit_Type__c=='Studio')**
[image]

```
for(Flat__c opp:[SELECT Unit_Type__c,Block__c,Total_Amount_Received_Formula__c,Total_Milestone_Payment_Formula__c,Id FROM Flat__c where Block__c=:accid ])
    {
           if(opp.Unit_Type__c=='Studio')
           {
           acc.Total_Milestone_Payment_studio__c  =acc.Total_Milestone_Payment_studio__c+opp.Total_Milestone_Payment_Formula__c;
           acc.Total_Payment_Received_Studio__c=acc.Total_Payment_Received_Studio__c+opp.Total_Amount_Received_Formula__c;
           }
           else if (opp.Unit_type__c=='1 BHK')
           {
               acc.Total_Milestone_Payment_1_BHK__c  =acc.Total_Milestone_Payment_1_BHK__c  +opp.Total_Milestone_Payment_Formula__c;
               acc.Total_Payment_Received_1_BHK__c=acc.Total_Payment_Received_1_BHK__c+opp.Total_Amount_Received_Formula__c;

           }
           else if (opp.Unit_Type__c=='Compact 2 BHK')
           {
                   acc.Total_Milestone_Payment_compact_2_BHK__c  =acc.Total_Milestone_Payment_compact_2_BHK__c+opp.Total_Milestone_Payment_Formula__c;
                   acc.Total_Payment_Received_compact_2_BHK__c =acc.Total_Payment_Received_compact_2_BHK__c +opp.Total_Amount_Received_Formula__c;


           }
           else if (opp.Unit_type__c=='2 BHK')
           {
                acc.Total_Milestone_Payment_2_BHK__c  = acc.Total_Milestone_Payment_2_BHK__c+opp.Total_Milestone_Payment_Formula__c;
                acc.Total_Payment_Received_2_BHK__c   = acc.Total_Payment_Received_2_BHK__c +opp.Total_Amount_Received_Formula__c;


           }
           else if(opp.Unit_type__c=='3 BHK')
           {
                acc.Total_Milestone_Payment_3_BHK__c  =acc.Total_Milestone_Payment_3_BHK__c+opp.Total_Milestone_Payment_Formula__c;
                acc.Total_Payment_Received_3_BHK__c =acc.Total_Payment_Received_3_BHK__c +opp.Total_Amount_Received_Formula__c;


           }



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is a series of if/else if/else statements the line number reported is usually the "if" though the error may be occurring on one of the later "else if" conditions.

If there are more "else if" than you show in your question check them all.